# GCP Dataflow Job Deployment

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to automate CI/CD of Classic Template.

Created and Staged template on GCS following the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/creating-templates)

On code changes (Bug fixes etc), I intend to drain the existing job and create a new job with the same name.

To [drain](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dataflow/jobs/drain) existing job, I need JOB_ID, but I have only JOB_NAME which I used during the creation of the job.

The only way i see is to use [list](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dataflow/jobs/list) command and fetch the active jobs, process the output to extract the job id to use it in the **drain** command. It seems to be quite a roundabout way. Isn't there a way to Drain a job with Job_Name or at least get JOB_ID from JOB_NAME.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GCP provides [REST API](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/rest/v1b3/projects.templates/launch) to update dataflow job. No need of explicitly draining the existing the job and creating a new job.

You can do it via Python Code too. Refer to my [GIST](https://gist.github.com/vinodjayachandran/5cddd038b0fc1886fec14ceda9b11126) for python code.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the [`gcloud dataflow jobs run`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dataflow/jobs/run) command to create the job, the response from running this command should return the `JOB_ID` in the following way (e.g. if you create a batch job):

```
    id: 2016-10-11_17_10_59-1234530157620696789
    projectId: YOUR_PROJECT_ID
    type: JOB_TYPE_BATCH
```

That and using the [`gcloud dataflow jobs list`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dataflow/jobs/list) as you mention will be the straightforward way to associate a `JOB_NAME` and a `JOB_ID` using automation. The way to achieve this with a Python script is described within this other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52374924/google-cloud-dataflow-python-retrieving-job-id/52386921) in the community.